# Calculate mean of one variable for each group and add it as new variable

Tags: spss

In my data set I have two variables as work experience (continuous) and work group (categorical- 20 different groups). Now I would like to calculate the mean of work experience for each group and add it as a third variable to my data set. 
would you please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aggregate` function does this.
use following syntax:

```
aggregate /outfile=* mode=addvariables/break=WorkGroup /Exp_mean=mean(WorkExp).
```